# Application of Feynman-Kac

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $u(t, x) = E_x[\int_0^t \! 1_{[-1,1]}(B(s))ds] = E[$Time spent by B(s) in $[-1, 1]$ up to time $t$ | $B(0) = x$]. 
write a differential equation for $u(t,x).$ Include appropriate boundary conditions.

Is this an application of Feynman-Kac formula? 
I think I was told to use an the identity $E(X)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}E(e^{\lambda x})$ evaluated at $\lambda = 0$. I don't know how to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define
$$v(t,x,y)=E_x[e^{\int_0^ty\mathbf1_{[-1,1]}(B(s))\ \mathrm{d}s}]$$
A simple application of Feynman-Kac shows that $v$ solves the PDE
$$v_t=\tfrac12v_{xx}+y\mathbf1_{[-1,1]}(x)v,\\
v(0,x,y)=1,\\
v(t,x,0)=1.$$
Differentiating the first two lines with respect to $y$ (and assuming appropriate continuity of the derivatives),
$$(v_y)_t=\tfrac12(v_y)_{xx}+(yv_y+v)\mathbf1_{[-1,1]}(x),\\
v_y(0,x,y)=0.$$
Now by your hint we know that $u(t,x)=v_y(t,x,0)$. Evaluating everything at $y=0$, it follows that $u$ solves the PDE
$$u_t=\tfrac12u_{xx}+\mathbf1_{[-1,1]}(x),\\
u(0,x)=0.$$

Comment: That makes sense thanks a lot.